# How to call GetPrice method by passing converted value into txtQty?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm not sure if I'm writing the call correctly. 'intQty' says doesn't exist in current context. So how would I go about fixing that?

```
txtQty.Text = getPrice(intQty); 

txtPrice.Text = decPrice.ToString("C2");

//Also to compute the order total it has to be written as
Order Total = (Order Qty * Price) * (1 + Tax Rate)
```

**what I have:** decTotal = (intQty * decPrice) * (1 + fltTaxRate);

so would I replace the that with values I've already declared?
EDIT: **'intQty' is declared right under the btnCalculate_Click as 'int intQty;'
there's data validation underneath and some methods as well.**

**FULL CODE:**

```
        string sCboStates;
        int intQty;
        string sWrapperSample;
        // data validation
        try
        {
            intQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQty.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contents are not numeric.",
                            "Quantity",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtQty.Focus();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            sWrapperSample = Convert.ToString(txtWrapperSample.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Content's empty.",
                            "Wrapper Sample",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            txtLine1.Focus();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            sCboStates = Convert.ToString(cboStates.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Content's empty.",
                            "States",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            cboStates.Focus();
            return;
        }
    }
      // Method 1

    private decimal getPrice(int intQty)
    {
        decimal decPrice;

        if (intQty <= 500)
        {
            decPrice = 1.25m;
        }
        else if (intQty >= 501 && intQty <= 1000)
        {
            decPrice = 1.05m;
        }
        else if (intQty >= 1001 && intQty <= 5000)
        {
            decPrice = .90m;
        }
        else if (intQty > 5001)
        {
            decPrice = .75m;
        }
        decPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text);
        txtQty.Text = intQty.ToString();
        return intQty;

    }

    //Method 2
    private float getTaxRate(string sCboStates)
    {
        string sStates = "";
        float fltTaxRate=0;

        if (sStates == "CT")
        {
           fltTaxRate = 0.06f;
        }
        else if (sStates == "MA")
        {
            fltTaxRate =.0625f;
        }
        else if (sStates == "ME")
        {
            fltTaxRate = .085f;
        }
        else if (sStates == "NH")
        {
            fltTaxRate = .0f;
        }
        else if (sStates == "RI")
        {
            fltTaxRate = .07f;
        }
        else if (sStates == "VT")
        {
            fltTaxRate = .06f;
        }
        return fltTaxRate;
      }

      //Method 3
      private void formatWrapperSample()
      {
          txtWrapperSample.Text = txtLine1.Text + " " +
                     Environment.NewLine +
                     txtLine2.Text + " " +
                     Environment.NewLine +
                     txtLine3.Text;
      }
      // Method 4

      private Color GetColor(string sColorIn)
      {
        return Color.FromName(sColorIn);

        //CALCULATIONS
        decimal decTotal = 0;

         //Call the price method by passing the numeric value and the text qty

        txtQty.Text = getPrice(intQty);
        txtPrice.Text = decPrice.ToString("C2");

         // Compute the total

        decTotal = (intQty * decPrice) * (1 + fltTaxRate);
        txtTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("C2"); 
     }

     private void cboWrapperColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        //Label Color 'cboWrapperColor_Selected' is a typo  
         txtWrapperSample.BackColor = GetColor(cboLabelColor.Text);  
     }

     private void cboFontColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         txtWrapperSample.ForeColor = GetColor(cboFontColor.Text);
     }

     private void cboStates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         getTaxRate("P2");
     }

     private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         txtLine1.Clear();
         txtLine2.Clear();
         txtLine3.Clear();
         txtQty.Clear();
         txtWrapperSample.Clear();
     }

     private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Application.Exit(); 
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well does intQty exist? You need to show us where it is being declared/assigned.

Comment: `Order Total = (Order Qty * Price) * (1 + Tax Rate)` this is not valid C# syntax. Spaces are not allowed in identifiers.

Comment: I know it isn't. That isn't the code, just the example for the order. I'll add where 'intQty' is declared.

Comment: We need to see the code in order to help you debug your issue. There isn't enough detail here to give you an answer.

Comment: You need to post your full code. If `intQty` is defined locally in a different method, you won't be able to access it from another method's "context".

Comment: Chances are you have defined your intQty within a specific method and it is not visible to other methods. Place the declaration at the class level and make it public to be able to access it from all methods of your class.

Comment: I've added all code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is some code missing, is everything starting with `//CALCULATIONS` to the end of the code part of the `GetColor()` method?

At any rate, you're declaring and initializing `intQty` in your `btnCalculate_Click` event handler.  This means that the rest of your program does not know about `intQty` (with the exception of `GetPrice()` since you're passing it in).

Declare `intQty` as a global variable at the top of your class and then set the correct value in `btnCalculate_Click`

That way when you go to do the calculations it will know about `intQty`

Comment: calculations aren't a part of the GetColor Method. I just did them in order of operation on my instructions sheet.

Comment: Then what method are they a part of? The way your code is currently formatted in the OP they're in `GetColor()` (but wouldn't be called because of the `return` statement before it).  Fix your code and I'll update my answer if needed

Comment: they're apart of the GetPrice method. Thanks. I'll figure it out.

Comment: As @Saggio has pointed out, you have put that code in the GetColor() method, and those lines don't belong there. Perhaps they should have been placed in GetPrice()

Comment: I removed it and placed it under the GetPrice method instead. The only problem I have now is that 'fltTaxRate' says value doesn't exist. Not sure where I'm going wrong as I've already declared it

Comment: @user4338480 you're declaring `fltTaxRate` in the `GetTaxRate()` method, `GetPrice()` has no idea about it.  If you need to use the same variables in multiple methods, you need to either make them global variables (move `float fltTaxRate=0;` to the top of your class before your methods) or pass them in as arguments to the methods that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Also...

You are using exceptions to control program flow, which is generally considered bad practice.

Exceptions are for exceptional cases, because they are computationally expensive.

You should use Int32.TryParse() instead

Comment: There is also Hungarian notation used which is not recommended in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
txtQty.Text = getPrice(intQty);
```

For one your method returns `Decimal` - you can't assign it to `String` property. C# is stringly typed.